# Alternative to nested tables

Tags: html, html-table, nested

I am currently using html nested tables to present the output from a SQL query. However, since html nested tables take up a lot of memory I am looking for an alternative. Could I somehow create several tables next to each other which achieve the same result?

Option 1 - current solution:

```
<table>
<td>
<table class='s'>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</td>
</td>
<table class='s'>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</td>
</table>
```

**Option 2**

```
<table class='s'>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>

...

<table class='s'>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

PS. sorry for the weird formatting above, it kept cutting out my code with the tags

Comment: Where did you get the idea that nested tables take up up a lot of memory?

Comment: If I have a lot of nested tables (>100 columns and >100 rows per column) it will take a lot of memory by the browser. If I only have >10 columns with 10000 rows then it goes much faster. Where did you get the idea that nested tables does not take up a lot of memory?

Comment: IF you display a lot of information on a page, it will take a lot of memory, no matter what you use to display it. I think you are looking at the problem the wrong way. There is no way that all that information needs to be loaded at once on the browser

Comment: Why not try to get a better understanding on how the user uses the information and work from there? Like using ajax to expand the nested tables when needed

Comment: You can also introduce paging for the main table

Comment: @Sergio - the users want the complete information displayed at once. The users have the possibility to search for different date ranges, e.g. from 2013-07-20 to 2013-07-26 and so on. To avoid any misunderstanding here; even if a user select data for 2013-01-01 to 2013-12-31 this will still load quickly vertically as long as there are not too many columns horizontally. However, when working with nested tables, the browser looks at the end of the table before printing out the table and that is causing the browser to consume a lot of memory. The server side memory is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

Since paging isn't an option...

You're right that it doesn't matter what technology you're using - more curiosity than anything on my part.  Also, I'm not familiar with PHP so take my ideas as abstract here please.  Have you tried/considered the following (I created a fiddle to demonstrate the graphical portion of this http://jsfiddle.net/ninja1/ynuDV/):

- Use CSS "table" to define that the display for any/all "tables" in that given page use `display:inline-block;`
- Render first table without any nesting. Use a button or whatever control you wish to have a lever/key/rowId/userId whatever you have that would reflect your selection.
- You'd then intercept this control's action, if a button - then whenever the button is clicked it would then call a method to create the second table dynamically and programmatically based upon the selection from table1.
- Once table 2 has been rendered with input from table1, the same rule would apply to table2.  Use a control again and capture/leverages the selection from table2 to then end up being the input for table3 to be created programmatically.

As you can see by the fiddle I've attached here; try resizing the pane by grabbing the center divider and moving it left/right. You'll notice that the tables line-up next to each other should the display size allow them to.

Hope this helps :) let me know.

---

I think the best approach here is to make paging available to the table.

Additionally, you could allow the user to set the size of the page that is rendered - therefore allowing them to optimize for their best performance.  So you would have a textbox underneath the table that the user can edit and is pre-populated with your initial decision of let's say 20 records per page.

Lastly, make sure to implement the SQL query/stored proc with a page-size and page number parameters so the database does the logic and only returns the dataset required. 
Consider something like this http://blog.sqlauthority.com/tag/sql-paging/

Comment: Fenix - paging is not an alternative, what I am looking for is a way to print out multiple tables next to each other vertically. so instead of using a nested table, I would like to know how to print out a first table, and then having table 2 to the right of it, table 3 to the right of table 2 etc.

Comment: Are you using c#?  If you are then you could code building tables dynamically/programmatically based on the data.  What are the technologies that you're leveraging or could leverage?

Comment: It is with PHP. I don't see how C# should be different though. I want to programatically create tables next to each other, without using nested tables. It should somehow be possible by creating separate tables that end up next to each other based on css and html formatting purely, right?